# How to stack date properties neatly with css

Tags: html, css

I have the following div in an app I'm working on:

```
<div>
  <mat-card *ngFor="let notification of notifications">
    <div class="notif-card">
      <h4 class="startDate">{{formatDate(notification.start_date)}}</h4>
      <h4 class="name">{{notification.payor_name}}</h4>
      <div class="card-desc">
        <h4 class="linkText" (click)="getDocUrl(notification.doc_id)">{{domParser(notification.name)}}</h4>
        <button class="notes" (click)="navigateToNotes(notification.id)">View Notes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
  </mat-card>
</div>
```

This is the css for the `startDate` class:

```
.startDate {
  border-right: 3px solid #f2c413;
  height: 60px;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  width: 5%;
}
```

Currently the start dates show up like this:
[image]

But I'd like them to be a little bit neater, like with the day shifter to the right a bit and those date properties generally just stacked neater.

How could I achieve this? If you need it, below is the entire css file:

```
@admin-link-blue: #0078D3;

.notif-menu {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 4%;
  background: #f4f4f4;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.page-title {
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.menu-title {
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.menuPart {
  background: var(--bs-body-bg);
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.heading {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.search {
  margin-top: 25px;
  background: #009aa6;
  color: white;
}

.startDate {
  border-right: 3px solid #f2c413;
  height: 60px;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  width: 5%;
}

.name {
  border-right: 1px solid gray;
  height: 100px;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #797979;
  letter-spacing: 0.25rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 15%;
}

.notif-card {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 20px;
}

.card-desc {
  width: 80%;
}

.linkText {
  color: #0078d5;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.notes {
  background:none;
  border:none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #009aa6;
}

.paging-wrap {
  height: 90px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;

  .clickable {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: @admin-link-blue;

    &:hover {
      text-decoration: underline;
    }
  }

  i.fa, .page-info {
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "stacked neater"? Can you upload an img of what you'd like to get?

Comment: put your display notif-card with display grid, 3 columns, 1 row. After you can adjust size of each column, position of element inside a cell and so on